# H2 database org.h2.Driver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit4, h2

I try to run JUNIT test with eclipse and ANT they both are complainen that org.h2.Driver class is not found.

I have h2-1.3.164.jar in my classpath and for proof about it here is classpath from system property java.class.path

`c:\trasferer\build;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared\plugins\org.junit4_4.3.1\junit.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib\ojdbc6.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\h2-1.3.164.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\junit-4.8.2.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\log4j-1.2.14.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\TestUtils.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\dbunit-2.4.8.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar;
c:\trasferer\lib-test\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.5.jar;`

and I can found class org.h2.Driver from h2-1.3.164.jar when I open it with eclipse.
Ant task for running test and ANT tasks for "build" classpath

```
<path id="lib.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./lib" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="lib-test" includes="*.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${dest}" />
    <pathelement location="${test-dest}" />
</path>

<target name="run-test" depends="init-test,compile,compile-test">
    <property name="classPathToUse" refid="test.classpath" />
    <echo>Using classpath: "${classPathToUse}"</echo>
    <junit failureProperty="test.failure" fork="on" forkmode="once" outputtoformatters="true" printsummary="on" showoutput="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Duser.timezone=GMT" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dexternal-properties=${test.properties}" />
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="test-results">
            <fileset dir="${test-dest}" includes="**/*Test.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
    <fail message="test failed" if="test.failure" />
</target>
```

and here is stacktrace

```
    [junit] ------------- Standard Error -----------------
    [junit] log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
    [junit] log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
    [junit] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.dbunit.DatabaseTestCase).
    [junit] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] Testcase: testBuildLiityntapisteSQL(org.xyz.rigistry.manager.XXServiceImplTest):     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] org.h2.Driver
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
    [junit]     at org.dbunit.JdbcDatabaseTester.(JdbcDatabaseTester.java:104)
    [junit]     at org.dbunit.PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.(PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.java:68)
    [junit]     at org.dbunit.DBTestCase.newDatabaseTester(DBTestCase.java:70)
    [junit]     at org.dbunit.DatabaseTestCase.getDatabaseTester(DatabaseTestCase.java:109)
    [junit]     at org.dbunit.DatabaseTestCase.setUp(DatabaseTestCase.java:151)
    [junit]     at fi.transferer.junit.AbstractDatabaseTestCase.setUp(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at fi.transferer.junit.BasicDatabaseTestCase.setUp(Unknown Source)
```

So could someone tell me what is going on, please?

Comment: Could you post the stack you get ?

Comment: If the jar is already there in eclipse classpath, try doing clean and build. It might solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post the ANT build file section, which runs junit? There are options that switch off use of the CLASSPATH environment variable....

---

Relying on environment variables makes your build less portable and in my experience is a very inflexible way to manage your java dependencies. I notice you're already running into the problem of multiple versions of the same library (two copies of junit and log4j).

I would suggest altering your build to declare classpaths at the top of the **build.xml** file as follows:

```
<path id="compile.path">
    <fileset dir="c:\trasferer\lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<path id="test.path">
    <path refid="compile.path"/>
    <fileset dir="c:\trasferer\lib-test" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

These classpaths can then be used in the various ant tasks, using the **classpathref** attribute:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpathref="compile.path"
         debug="on"
         source="1.4"
  />
```

And junit has a nested classpath capability (useful for adding the compiled classes directory):

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
    <path refid="test.path"/>
  </classpath>

  <formatter type="plain"/>

  <test name="my.test.TestCase" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
    <formatter type="xml"/>
  </test>

  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
      <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
      <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that I have multiple junit and log4j libraries in my path, I will sort them out and if it resolves my problem I will accept your post as answer

Answer (score 3):

I think you should simply add these jars to the project buildpath in Eclipse.